# How to use C# 10 global using alias, for generic types?

Tags: c#

I have a generic class:

```
public Company.DataAccess.Repository<Model>
```

And I also have a global `Usings.cs` file to centralize and DRY my using statements.

Now I want to create an alis for the `Repository`. But this line does not work:

```
global using Repo = Company.DataAccess.Repository;
```

C# compiler complains that:

> error CS0305: Using the generic type 'Repository' requires 1 type arguments

Does this mean that I can't define aliases for my generic types?

Comment: `Company.DataAccess.Repository`, if it names a type, names a non-generic type called `Repository`. That you happen to have a generic type called `Repository<Model>` in that same namespace is of no relevance - the only "association" between those types is one in your own mind.

Comment: Never mind my earlier comments. As the duplicate link states, the using X=Y type aliasing doesn't support open generics.

Comment: This question specifically asks about a new language feature being global using. At the time of the answer  that keyword did not exist yet. The answer probably still applies but an explanation why global using also does not work is in order. How can a question asking about a newer feature in .NET ever be a duplicate of a question answered years before global using existed ?